# Firestore to Python Dictionary Speed Up with Multiprocessing?

Tags: python, performance, dictionary, google-cloud-firestore, multiprocessing

I tried several methods and found out the fastest way to load data from Firestore to Python dict is

```
dict = {doc.id: doc.to_dict() for doc in docs_ref}
```

But still, since we have the large-size collections in Firestore, it takes longer than 2-5 mins to merely load data.

I'm not familiar with multiprocessing, but we got a 4-core CPU. Is there a way, in this case, to leverage multiprocessing in Python to speed up the whole process?

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: have you referred this link https://googleapis.dev/python/firestore/latest/index.html#example-usage ?

Comment: Yes. I think it's the same? If I'm wrong, please correct me. I hope we are able to process multiple streams at the same time.